# Не отображаются объекты на сцене QGraphicsScene

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt, pyqt6, qgraphicsscene

Задача была следующая - создаем сцену и добавляем на нее много объектов в другом потоке, пока объекты добавляются, сама сцена не виснет, т.е. я могу передвигаться скроллами по сцене без фризов, да еще и видеть постепенно добавляющиеся объекты. Рассмотрим реализацию:

Создаем стандартную сцену и задаем ей размер (50000 х 1000), а так же поток, в котором будем добавлять на сцену объекты:

```
class Widget_GraphSurface(QWidget):

    ggv_main: QGraphicsView

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # init settings
        self.setMinimumSize(2000, 1200)
        self.show()
        # initial main layout
        self.lay_main = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.lay_main)
        # init lay graph
        self.lay_graph = QHBoxLayout()
        # add control panel and graph lays to main lay
        self.lay_main.addLayout(self.lay_graph)
        # main scene graph
        self.mainScene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.mainScene.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QColor('#ff333333')))
        # graphics view of main scene
        self.ggv_main = QGraphicsView(self.mainScene)
 self.ggv_main.setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView.ViewportAnchor.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.ggv_main.setResizeAnchor(QGraphicsView.ViewportAnchor.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.ggv_main.setFrameShape(QFrame.Shape.NoFrame)
        self.lay_graph.addWidget(self.ggv_main)
        self.ggv_main.scene().setSceneRect(0, 0, 50000, 1000)
        self.moveThread = MoveThread(self.mainScene)
        self.moveThread.start()
```

Поток:

```
class MoveThread(QThread):

    def __init__(self, scene: QGraphicsScene):
        super().__init__()

        self.scene = scene

    def run(self):
        try:
            i = 0
            while i < 50000:
                item = QGraphicsRectItem(i, 50, 45, 45)
                self.scene.addItem(item)
                i += 50
                time.sleep(0.001)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Все отлично работает, квадратики

> `QGraphicsRectItem(i, 50, 45, 45)`

добавляются на сцену, сцена не виснет, пока они добавляются. Но, самих квадратов не видно(кроме первых двух), но они есть на сцене! Ни метод `update`, ни метод `show` не помогают. Почему видно только первые два квадратика - я не могу понять. Квадратики отображаются только в двух случаях:

- Если не задавать заранее сцене размеры, то квадратики будут добавляться и автоматически расширять сцену в ширину и в таком случае они видны
- Если добавлять все объекты через основной `main` поток, но мне это не нужно
- Самая дурость в том, что если после добавления всех квадратиков, вызвать `scene.setSceneRect` и задать значение высоты отличное от заданного ранее на 1 пиксель, все квадратики отобразятся!!!
  Как это работает? Почему такие проблемы с отображением объектов, если их добавили из другого потока?

Answer (score 0):

В основном потоке работает графическая часть,
поэтому в дополнительных потоках не следует изменять напрямую,
это нужно сделать, отправив сигнал в основной поток
и именно в его слоте обновляется графическая часть.

В следующем примере создается сигнал,
который выдается каждые 10 ms в дополнительном потоке,
он подключается к слоту `add_item()` и именно там добавляем объект.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MoveThread(QThread):
# +++
    signal = pyqtSignal(object)                                      # +++
    
    def __init__(self):                 #-, scene: QGraphicsScene):
        super().__init__()
#-       self.scene = scene

    def run(self):
#?        try:
        i = 0
        while i < 50000:                             
            item = QGraphicsRectItem(i, 50, 45, 45)
#-           self.scene.addItem(item)
            self.signal.emit(item)
            i += 50
                
#-                time.sleep(0.001)
            self.msleep(10)
#?        except Exception as e:
#?            print(e)


class Widget_GraphSurface(QWidget):
    ggv_main: QGraphicsView

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(2000, 1200)
#        self.show()
        
        # initial main layout
        self.lay_main = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.lay_main)
        
        # init lay graph
        self.lay_graph = QHBoxLayout()
        # add control panel and graph lays to main lay
        self.lay_main.addLayout(self.lay_graph)
        
        # main scene graph
        self.mainScene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.mainScene.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QColor('#ff333333')))
        
        # graphics view of main scene
        self.ggv_main = QGraphicsView(self.mainScene)
        self.ggv_main.setTransformationAnchor(
            QGraphicsView.ViewportAnchor.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.ggv_main.setResizeAnchor(QGraphicsView.ViewportAnchor.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.ggv_main.setFrameShape(QFrame.Shape.NoFrame)
        self.ggv_main.scene().setSceneRect(0, 0, 50000, 1000)
        self.lay_graph.addWidget(self.ggv_main)
        
        self.moveThread = MoveThread()                #- self.mainScene
# +++
        self.moveThread.signal.connect(self.add_item)                  # +++
        self.moveThread.start()
        
        self.i = 1                                                     # +

# +++        
    def add_item(self, item):                                          # +++
        self.mainScene.addItem(item)                                   # +++
        
        x = item.rect().x()
        y = item.rect().y()

        self.text = QGraphicsTextItem()
        self.text.setHtml(f'<center>{self.i}</center>')
        self.text.setTextWidth(item.boundingRect().width())
        self.text.setDefaultTextColor(QColor('#fff')) 
        self.text.setPos(x, y+10)
        self.mainScene.addItem(self.text)
        self.i += 1
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget_GraphSurface()
    w.show()                                                         # +
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это все хорошо, но если в слоте что-то менять, например в цикле `for` перебирать около 500 объектов сцены, изменять им хотя бы цвет, все равно будет блокироваться основной поток отрисовки, и сцена будет зависать до тех пор пор, пока не закончатся расчеты или изменения цвета объекта. Этот вопрос я уже проработал - к сожалению QT может использовать только один поток. Либо если нужно, то можно делать расчеты в другом потоке и из него вызывать слот основного по сигналу, как в вашем примере. Может в каких-то случаях это будет рационально, но в основном именно в моей задаче нечего кардинально не мен

Comment: @Duracell вы спросили и привели конкретный пример, я вам ответил. Сейчас вы начинаете рассуждать, а если например что-то делать еще ... , к чему это? Если к вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: я не рассуждаю, а говорю по факту - ваш ответ по моей таски - работать не будет, по причинам озвученным выше

Comment: @Duracell я вам еще раз, на всякий случай, скажу, что с графикой работаем только в основном потоке.